# Changing values in excel sheet then reading the true value of the cell containing the formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel workbook which lets me change one cell value which in turn changes the rest of the cells in that column.

It should then spit out an error value in a specific cell based on a formula.

However, whenever I try to read it using `openpyxl` I always get a `None` value for the cell.

My code:

```
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
path = "frd gene.xlsx"
mywb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
worksheet = mywb['Sheet1']
# cells M2, N2 are where the k constant, theta are stored respectively.

const = 100
worksheet['N2'] = theta
worksheet['M2'] = const
mywb.save(path)
mywb.close()
mywb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
print(worksheet['O12'].value)
```

I reload the workbook in data only mode to read it but I am returned with a None value.

Comment: Openpyxl doesn't evaluate the formula... the formula is never evaluated between your saving and reopening the workbook.

Comment: @BigBen ah I see - is there a way to evaluate it without manually typing the formula into python?

Comment: You have to use the Excel calculation engine (e.g. using xlwings or win32com).

Comment: @BigBen I see, I'll have a look at the documentation for xlwings